# How to retrieve or display the image (Using Image's URL) from GCP bucket using java?

Tags: image, file, google-cloud-platform, bucket

How to view the original image using the URL in the GCP bucket using java.
I used MediaLink. But it works for download not for View the Image/File.

Please, anyone, answer my question.

Comment: Share what you have already done, even if it doesn't work. Give us the context of your request.

Comment: As far as I understand, you would like to create an URL in order to view your image that you have stored in GCS.

Your URL should be like:

`https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-bucket-name/myImage.jpg.`